# IN statement in Linq

Tags: sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

can anyone help me to write

```
Select * from students where studentid in 
(select studentXID from rel where parentXID = 123)
```

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: var q = db.table.Where(x => db.rel.Any(x2 => x2.parentXID == 123 && x.studentid == x2.studentXID))

Answer (score 0):

In linq, it's easier to split statements like that into two parts

```
var relList = context.rel.Where(x => x.parentXID = 123);

var result = context.students.Where(x => relList.studentXID.Contains(x.studentid));
```

Answer (score -1):

This should cover it

students.Where(s => rel.Any(r => r.studentXID == s.studentid && r.studentXID == 123))